# Effect of milk on effectiveness of oral tetracycline

Tags: medications, antibiotics

Tetracycline is known to be inhibited by calcium ions, and milk contains quite some calcium ions. What I want to ask is, to what extent does drinking milk affect the effectiveness of orally taken tetracycline?

Comment: @user19679 yes I figured it was a chelator, so binding tendency should be very strong. However what I want to know is how much milk actually affects tetracycline effectiveness, also considering *in vivo* conditions.

Comment: What dose have you been prescribed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Health.SE! Personal medical advice is off-topic here, so I have removed the part of, our question that could be constructed as asking for it. In my opinion, your question can stand alone without it.

Comment: @user19679 you have been told before  not to answer in comments, so why do you continue to do so instead of writing an answer? This is clearly an answer with medical advice that needs references and a way for the community to downvote it of it's wrong. Please convert it to an answer instead of continuing to give medical advice like this.

Comment: @user19679 and if you have a problem with that policy, feel free to discuss it on Meta instead of in the comments: http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/378/should-answers-in-comments-be-immediately-deleted

Comment: @YviDe I'm occupied 7 days a week, 12 hours a day; I just want to chip in still. Sorry... :-( People are more than welcome to re-claim my comments and utilise them accordingly. If I was making absurd claims and preaching unrealistic science, I'd understand the conflcition -- but I'm not. Sorry.

Comment: @user19679 - This site has policies, which you are not respecting. That's not only unhelpful, it's actively disrespectful. Please read [Should answers in comments be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/169). Feel free to chip in with an answer. If that takes too much time, than please pass.

Comment: @YviDe So does that mean, that although I am not seeking medical advice, I still shouldn't add my personal conditions here, even for context? I'm indeed new to Health.SE, so please enlighten me :-)

Comment: @busukxuan quite frankly, that paragraph I edited out read like asking for medical advice for me. The note about being able to extend the treatment made it sound to me like you might just choose to do a longer treatment duration if your eating interfered with the tetracycline. Otherwise, I am not quite sure why you included that information. (again, the question is good and can totally stand on its own without the context)

Comment: @YviDe oh, alright…the paragraph just intents to let people estimate the dosage. I am already avoiding milk before asking this question just to be safe, so this question has absolutely no effect on me. The treatment length will be the doctor's decision. Don't worry, I understand why the site prohibits medical advice, and I know how to be a good patient when in need of medical attention. Anyway thank you :-)

Comment: @busukxuan awesome, and sorry for the misunderstanding then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calcium-rich food interferes with absorption of tetracycline considerably:

> Milk and other dairy products, antacids containing polyvalent cations, as well as various iron salts ingested simultaneously with tetracycline derivatives, might interfere with their absorption by **50 to 90% or even more**.

[Interactions with the Absorption of Tetracyclines](http://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00003495-197611010-00004)

However, you can't *calculate* with that, by for example just taking twice the dosage. The safe method is to not ingest milk or any other calcium-rich food together with the tetracycline. The recommendation appears to be to [leave one to two hours between the antibiotics and milk](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/tetracycline-class-oral-route-parenteral-route/proper-use/drg-20069585) (taking the antibiotics first) :

> Do not take milk, milk formulas, or other dairy products within 1 to 2 hours of the time you take tetracyclines (except doxycycline and minocycline) by mouth

The study referenced above recommends an even more cautious three hours.